# In C#, what is the best way to sort two or more arrays of different data type? Array.Sort seems to except only one data type at a time

Tags: c#, arrays, types, int

I am able to sort an array using a single datatype such as string, but how can I sort other arrays with different datatypes and follow the ascending order that same string datatype?

As you can see I have one `Array.Sort` method near the bottom of my code with the `playerName` and `playerPosition` arrays being sorted. I'd like to add the int[] arrays `atBats` and `hits`. Then I need to add the batting average also which is a float value.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//My Baseball application named BatStat
namespace BatStat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //My declared variables that hold the user input in memory
            string teamName;
            string[] playerName = new string[3];
            string[] playerPosition = new string[3];
            int[] atBats = new int[3];
            int[] hits = new int[3];


            //Begin program by requesting user to enter team name value
            WriteLine("Welcome to Bat Stat, enter team name");
            teamName = Console.ReadLine();

            //Traverse all arrays and accumalate values from user input
            for (int i = 0; i < playerName.Length; i++)
            {
                WriteLine("Enter players name");
                playerName[i] = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("Enter Players Position");
                playerPosition[i] = ReadLine();
                WriteLine("Enter Players at bats");
                atBats[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                WriteLine("Enter Players hits");
                hits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
            }

            //Display top row menu for Bat Stat table
            WriteLine("{0, -10}{1, -10}{2, -5}{3, -5}{4, -5}{5, -5}", "Team", "Player", "Pos", "AB", "H", "BA");

            //for loop to traverse the arrays and display user input data in tabular format
            for (int x = 0; x < playerName.Length; ++x)
            {
                Array.Sort(playerName, playerPosition);
                float playerBA = (float)hits[x] / atBats[x];
                WriteLine("{0, -10}{1, -10}{2, -5}{3, -5}{4, -5}{5, -4}", teamName, playerName[x], playerPosition[x], atBats[x].ToString("d"), hits[x].ToString("d"), playerBA.ToString("F3"));
            }

            //Display the team batting average at bottom in a single row
            float teamBA = (float)hits.Sum() / atBats.Sum();
            WriteLine("The batting average for the {0} is {1}", teamName, teamBA.ToString("F3"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really create a class to hold all the related data and put those into one collection to sort on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're coding in C#, an Object-Oriented language, you should consider using objects.
You could declare your own class for the Player, holding the information you enter each time.

Then, when you sort by the player name and position, all the fields are sorted because you are sorting all players between them as a whole, not a specific field.

You could define your class as:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int AtBats { get; set; }
    public int Hits { get; set; }
}
```

You can get rid of the multiple arrays, and use:
`Player[] players = new Player[3];`

And in your loop, you can create the players like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
{
    var player = new Player();
    WriteLine("Enter players name");
    player.Name = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter Players Position");
    player.Position = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter Players at bats");
    player.AtBats = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    WriteLine("Enter Players hits");
    player.Hits = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    players[i] = player;
}
```

Hope that clears things up a bit and gets you started.

As for the comparison itself, you have multiple ways to do that.
If you want to use Array instead of List, the most straightforward way would be to have `Player` implement the `IComparable` interface. That way each Player object will know how to compare itself with another player.

If I understand correctly, you want to sort them first by Name, and then by Position? Then you can modify the Player class to be:

```
public class Player : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int AtBats { get; set; }
    public int Hits { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;
        var otherPlayer = obj as Player;
        int result = this.Name.CompareTo(otherPlayer.Name);
        if (result == 0) 
        {
            result = this.Position.CompareTo(otherPlayer.Position);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, to sort the players will be a simple call: `Array.Sort(players);` and the second loop of your program becomes:

```
//for loop to traverse the arrays and display user input data in tabular format
Array.Sort(players);
for (int x = 0; x < players.Length; x++)
{
    var player = players[i];
    float playerBA = (float)player.Hits / player.AtBats;
    WriteLine("{0, -10}{1, -10}{2, -5}{3, -5}{4, -5}{5, -4}", teamName, player.Name, player.Position, player.AtBats, player.Hits, playerBA.ToString("F3"));
}
```

Just a note: you were sorting the array 3 times, but you only needed it once. Here that you have 3 elements it doesn't make a difference, but if you had much more elements it would cost you.

You also don't need the `.ToString("d")`, as it's the default for an integer, and the conversion `.ToString()` is happening automatically when you call WriteLine.

Comment: How can I access those values within your for loop from outside the scope of that loop to be used in a WriteLine statement?

Comment: The array is defined in the outmost scope of the program. Each item in the array is an object and there you will find the values you need. How exactly do you want to access them?

Comment: Should the Player class be declared outside or inside the Main() scope?

Comment: Normally in OOP the classes are declared in a separate scope, outside from the Main() method and the Program class, usually in a separate file, even.

Comment: In trying to use input value player.Name from outside the for loop in a WriteLine method I get a "The name 'player' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You don't have a specific player in that line, but he is stored in the array of all players. You can access him like you did when you had the fields in 4 separate arrays, only it's simpler now. With a single access to the array, you get all the info for each player.

Comment: I am trying to use it outside the scope of the loop like this.WriteLine("{0, -10}{1, -10}{2, -5}{3, -5}{4, -5}{5, -4}", teamName, player.Name, player.Position, player.AtBats.ToString("d"), player.Hits.ToString("d"), playerBA.ToString("F3"));

Comment: I have added the code you need in my answer, to keep the proper formatting

Comment: I tried to compile your second loop and I get, System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.'

Comment: Huh, you're right. It seems you have to implement both IComparable and IComparable<Player> after all. Would that help? I'm on mobile now so I can't test it

Comment: How would I implement IComparable to sort  using the Name string? I've tried a few methods but still not getting the results I'm looking for.

Comment: You have to implement it on the Player class, like the IComparable implementation I provided in the answer

Comment: That IComparable implementation worked, thank you very much, really appreciate your time and support!